CMake Error: G++ broken when using aarch64-none-elf toolchain for cross compiling TensorFlow Lite C API
I would like to cross-compile the tensorflow lite C API with my arm GNU toolchain. I have thus created a Cmake toolchain file. However I am getting this error:
Anyone knows where the issue lies?
`
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc - works
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-g++ - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/...../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-g++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /.../tfliteBuildAarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_3a21d/fast && /bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a21d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a21d.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/.../tfliteBuildAarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a21d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
    /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-g++   -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mcpu=cortex-a53 -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mcpu=cortex-a53  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a21d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c /.../tfliteBuildAarch64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_3a21d
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a21d.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-g++  -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mcpu=cortex-a53 -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mcpu=cortex-a53  CMakeFiles/cmTC_3a21d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -o cmTC_3a21d 
    /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(libc_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
    /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:65:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
    /.../arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
    /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:49:(.text._write_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_write'
    /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(libc_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
    /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:47:(.text._close_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_close'
    /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
    /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:49:(.text._lseek_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_lseek'
    /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(libc_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
    /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:49:(.text._read_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_read'
    /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /imec/other/arm4insi/projectdata/despir01/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/13.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(libc_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
    /data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-13/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:51:(.text._sbrk_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

`

I tried to disable in my .cmake toolchain file the C++ compiler setup because I only have C files. But it did not work and still tried to test the compiler.

You chose a toolchain that targets bare metal, not GNU. Try a toolchain that ends in -linux-gnu.

@Siguza I choose the aarch64-none-elf toolchain on purpose, I know it targets bare metal but that is because my simulation environment is on ModelSim and it requires compilation with bare metal as target.
How would aarch64-linux-gnu make a difference? I thought compiling tensorflow lite c API for bare metal as target would also be ok.

Does that tensorflow stuff require libc? If not, then you should add -nostdlib to CFLAGS. If it does require libc, then you'll have to implement a minimal set of platform functions that libc depends on (which you can probably reduce by using -flto, if that is feasible for you), put those in a library of your own, and add the flags to link to it to LDFLAGS.
